# Run docker container on k3s-agent from k3s-master

Tags: docker, ubuntu, kubernetes-pod, k3s

I made one `k3s-master` on ubuntu 20 and one `k3s-agent` on another ubuntu 20. I have both system connected to same network.I have docker image on k3s-agent, I can able to run the container on k3s-agent.I created one cluster and k3s-agent and k3s-master both are connected to cluster. I checked with `kubectl get nodes` command on master and I can see agent and master are listed.

I need help on following points.
I want to run docker image on k3s-agent from k3s-master. Is there any way to run docker image on agent from master ?

I came to know that I can make pod and using pod I can do that. but pod is not working out.

Comment: Hi @emre-odabaş, I tried your solution and I am one more step ahead of goal, but I am facing error of 'ErrImagePull' while getting pod status, the pod is pulling image from docker website.I already have that image on agent machine. is there any key that I can set value in 'pod.yaml' file that can use node`s local image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things we can do.

1. `nodeName`,

Just mention the `nodeName: mynode1` in yaml file.

2. `taints and toleration`

We can set `Taints and Toleration` inside pod`s yaml file. Example below.

set Taints to node like this

```
kubectl taint nodes mynode1 app=Device:NoSchedule
```

and we can toleration in yaml file as below.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: scriptpod
spec:
  containers:
    - name: scriptdo
      image: scriptdo
      imagePullPolicy: Always
nodeName: mynode1
restartPolicy: Always
tolerations:
- key: "app"
  operator: "Equal"
  value: "Device"
  effect: "NoSchedule"
```

[Document for taints and toleration](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/taint-and-toleration/)

Note:- I set `nodeName` and `taints and toleration` both, cause `nodeName` not worked in rare case.

Answer (score 1):

If I did not misunderstand, you could simply deliver your docker image with kubectl command like;
`kubectl run my-pod --image=your-image ...`

If you desire to run pods on the agent-side then you could use `taint` and `toleration` abilities to match pods and nodes.

Comment: I will let you know, once I will try your answer, Right now I am facing some more errors to run k3s service on both agent and master so I am working on it.

Answer (score 0):

One option to run a docker image on your agent node is that you can build the image locally on that node. Once it is built, you can set the `imagePullPolicy: Never` so it will try to grab it from the agent's local docker registry.

```
 spec:
  affinity:
    nodeAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        nodeSelectorTerms:
          - matchExpressions:
              - key: <label key>
                operator: In
                values:
                  - <agent label> 
  containers:
    - name: <container name>
      image: <image name>
      imagePullPolicy: Never
```